# bc not executing via script

Tags: linux, bash, standard-deviation, bc

Hi I have a script which I am using to calculate the standard deviation from a set of values returned from a server.

I can easily retrieve the commands and build a valid string with the command.

```
bc <<< "scale=10; sqrt((0+((782636-782030)^2)+((781460-782030)^2)+((782492-782030)^2)+((781704-782030)^2)+((781860-782030)^2))/5)"
```

I create this command by itterating through an array and appending it to the string like so.

```
CMD='bc <<< "scale=10; sqrt((0'
for i in "${MEMORY[@]}"; do
    CMD=$CMD'+(('$i'-'$MEAN')^2)'
done;
CMD=$CMD')/5)"'
```

Once I have done this i then try to execute the command string into a variable

```
SD=`$CMD`   
echo $SD
```

However I am getting the output

```
File <<< is unavailable.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: You should also look at defining a standard deviation function directly in `bc`, rather than building up a long expression in `bash` to pass as a program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<<` needs to be parsed by the shell, which happens before parameter expansion. When you try to execute

```
SD=`$CMD`
```

the string in `$CMD` is not reparsed, so `<<<` is treated as a literal string and passed as an argument to `bc`. You need something like

```
BC_EXPRESSION='scale=10; sqrt((0'
for i in "${MEMORY[@]}"; do
    BC_EXPRESSION+="+(($i-$MEAN)^2)"
done
BC_EXPRESSION+=')/5)'

SD=$( bc <<< "$BC_EXPRESSION" )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should build your `bc` command in a string and then pass this string to `bc`.

If I understand correctly, you have an array of numbers `memory`<sup>1</sup> and a variable `mean` and you want to compute the standard deviation of `memory` (where, I guess, `mean` is the average of `memory`).

You need to build up strings of the form `(X-mean)^2`:

```
sum_terms=0
for i in "${memory[@]}"; do
    sum_terms+="+(($i)-($mean))^2"
done
```

At this point, the string `sum_terms` contains the string that expands to something like:

```
0+((m1)-(mean))^2+((m2)-(mean))^2+ ... +((mn)-(mean))^2
```

Finally, you want to enclose this in parentheses, prepend `sqrt(` and append `/5)` and pass it to `bc`:

```
bc <<< "sqrt(($sum_terms)/5)"
```

All in one:

```
sum_terms=0
for i in "${memory[@]}"; do
    sum_terms+="+(($i)-($mean))^2"
done
bc -l <<< "sqrt(($sum_terms)/5)"
```

Notice that I enclosed the `$mean` term in parentheses, just in case this is a negative number (it would otherwise clash with the preceding negative sign)—and while I was at it, I also enclosed the `$i` term in parentheses.

---

As a side note, you could also use `E((X-E(X))^2)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2` to compute the standard deviation, and also do it in a more generic way:

Given an array `memory`, compute its standard deviation:

```
memory=( 782636 781460 782492 781704 781860 )
sum_mem=0 sum_memsq=0
for i in "${memory[@]}"; do
    sum_mem+="+($i)"
    sum_memsq+="+($i)^2"
done
mean=$(bc -l <<< "($sum_mem)/${#memory[@]}")
bc -l <<< "sqrt(($sum_memsq)/${#memory[@]}-($mean)^2)"
```

---

In fact you don't really need the explicit `for` loop here, you can leave `printf` do the job for you:

```
memory=( 782636 781460 782492 781704 781860 )
printf -v sum_mem '+(%s)' "${memory[@]}"
printf -v sum_memsq '+(%s)^2' "${memory[@]}"
mean=$(bc -l <<< "(0$sum_mem)/${#memory[@]}")
bc -l <<< "sqrt((0$sum_memsq)/${#memory[@]}-($mean)^2)"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> let me lowercase all your variable names, uppercase variable names are considered bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
echo "scale=10; sqrt((0+((782636-782030)^2)+((781460-782030)^2)+((782492-782030)^2)+((781704-782030)^2)+((781860-782030)^2))/5)" | bc -l
```

i.e. `echo` your string and pipe the output to `bc -l`

This will work